# Passing string variable to function containing system() command in C

Tags: c, vbscript

I am aware of the other posts about this topic. But after reviewing all of them, there still seems to be a problem for my case.

Currently I am  working on a 'String to speech' function  using a `Vbscript` to convert a string to speech. (spraak.vbs) The `VBsript` is saved in the same folder as the C code.

Content of the `VBscript file with 1 argument

```
rem String to speech  
Set spkArgs = WScript.Arguments 
arg1 = spkArgs(0)
set speech =  Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice") 
speech.speak arg1
```

Using the sprintf() command i combined the total string for the system() command.

```
sprintf(command, "cmd /c spraak.vbs \"Welcome\"");
system(command);
```

The code used here works like a charm. But when i try to use a variable as my argument ("Welcome"). It only says "Empty".

```
char text = "\"Welcome\""
sprintf(command, "cmd /c spraak.vbs %s", text);
system(command);
```

What could be the problem?

Full C code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test\n");
    char text[] = "\"Welcome\"";
    char command[] = "";
    printf("%s\n", text);
         sprintf(command, "cmd /c spraak.vbs \"Welcome\"");
         system(command);
        sprintf(command, "cmd /c spraak.vbs %s", text);
        system(command);
    printf("Test2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many characters do you intent to store in `char command[]` ? Hint: They don't fit into that variable.

Comment: You seem to be confusing batch-file with Vbscript.

Comment: @Gerhardh You sir, just pointed out the exact problem. char command[] = "" gives an empty array.

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: @aschipfl I'm guessing because `cmd /c` isn't [tag:vbscript].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
char command[] = "";
```

That creates an array of a *single character*, and that single character is the string terminator `'\0'`. It's equal to

```
char command[1] = { '\0' };
```

When you use `sprintf` you write out of bounds, and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve this use a fixed size for the array, and use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to avoid buffer overflows:

```
char command[128];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "cmd /c spraak.vbs %s", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) needs an already allocated buffer of sufficient size to put its result in. Your `char command[] = ""` however, is an array of characters of length 1 (just the terminating null), which is too short to take the full result.

You might want to try using

```
char command[50];
```

instead. Please note, that in a real application, the `50` should be determined appropriately according to the data to be stored. To this end, you could use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) instead of `sprintf` to compute the required buffer size.